# Comparing array with single string to an array with plain texts if they contain the single texts

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, compare

since my last question couldn't get an answer i thought i should simplify it.

i got one array with

```
( "superman","batman","flash")
```

and one array with

```
("superman is the strongest superhero","batman is the most badass of all")
```

now as we can see superman and batman from first array exist in second array.

how can i make this comparison and if its true add the second array object to another array

I have tried to use NSPredicate but that didn't workout since i couldn't understand filter which array with what

Example

```
input array = (@"rice", @"chicken",@"tomato",@"egg")
```

and lets say i got 2 item from my database that one has 
`(@"100 gr rice",@"250 gr chicken")` and the other `(@"250 gr chicken",@"4 eggs",@"3 tomato@")`

with this current input. i need to able to add both of the items from my database to a finalArray to show it on a tableView.

Comment: Provide an example of the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying something like this, where you got some ingredients and you want to figure out what you can do with them from recipes.

```
NSArray *myIngredients = @[@"chicken", @"tomato", @"eggs"];

NSArray *myRecipes = @[
    @[@"olives",@"tomato",@"rice"],
    @[@"cheese",@"onion"],
    @[@"chicken",@"eggs"]
];
```

Recipes I got at least one ingredient for:

```
-(NSArray*)recipesForWhichIhaveAtLeastOneIngredient{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSArray *recipe in myRecipes){
        for(NSString *ingredient in myIngredients){
            if([recipe contains:ingredient]){
                [result addObject:recipe];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Recipes you can actually cook because you got all ingredients:

```
-(NSArray*)recipesICanCook{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSArray *recipe in myRecipes){
        BOOL gotAllIngredients = YES;

        for(NSString *ingredient in recipe){
            if(![myIngredients contains:ingredient]){
                gotAllIngredients = NO;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(gotAllIngredients){
            [result addObject:recipe];
        }
    }
}
```